PI 4 low network speed after connecting USB drive
USB drive is a SD card reader with a 1TB micro sd card in it.
It is formatted as exFAT. I had to install exfat-fuse, exfatprogs to make it visible in PI.
I noticed that after setting it up, and restarting the PI, the boot process took forever.
And after that the network speed dropped almost 10 times.
I know that PI gives very little power to the USB ports, that's why most SSD drives cannot be powered through the PI's USB, but the card reader needs very little power, should not consume more than 1A. And the drive works fine, it's the network that is getting affected.
This only seems to affect wireless network. With LAN connected, speeds are normal.
System load is around 0.3 on average and highest CPU time is used by the kworker/u13:0-brcmf_wq/mmc1:0001:1 process, around 6%.
OS is the headless PI 64 bit OS.
Any idea on what could be causing the network speed drop?

most SSD drives cannot be powered through the PI's USB - never had a problem with my 3 PI4's

I tried a with sandisk ssd and it didn't work at all.. Micro SD seems to work, but for me it causes random issues. Sometime doesn't boot, sometimes boots in 30 min. (probably continuous restarts).. It's also very hard for me to debug because all I have is ssh, which doesn't load if boot fails..

well, sounds like you have a power supply issue for a start. How are you powering your pi
